# Erlang remote shell debugging not working

Tags: debugging, erlang

I'm trying to debug Erlang node started on remote PC, from my local PC.
For debugging I'm using latest  IntelliJ Idea with Erlang plugin.

Remote node started like this:

```
erl -pa /path/to/myapp/ebin -name myapp@myremote.host -setcookie mycookie -shell -eval "application:start(myapp)."
```

Idea uses Rebar "Erlang Remote Node" configuration , so local node started and connected to  myapp@myremote.host.

I can confirm connection, because "nodes()." on remote shell show my connected node from local machine. Also net_adm ping/pong works.
"epmd -names" also show correspond sessions.

Unfortunately all my breakpoints within IDE not triggering, so I can't stop execution and perform step-by-step debugging via IDE.

Meantime such debug session works like a charm in case of both nodes started on local PC.

Please suggest me what I'm doing wrong. Many thanks in advance .

PS: I'm also tried with short node names, with same result.

Comment: As temporary workaround built-in erlang debugger can be used via ssh/X forwarding.

DISPLAY=:0 ssh -XC  my.host.name   erl -pa /path/to/project/ebin  -setcookie mycookie  -name myapp@my.host.name  -shell

From shell :  debugger:start().   application:start(myapp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup epmd for listening on external IP (http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html) and after that DNS name "myremote.host" should be resolve to it IP